# Error when using XML in Stored Procedure (PDO + MS SQL 2008)

Tags: php, xml, sql-server-2008, pdo

When I use SQL Profiler, I see all the requests coming from the Debian server and I can execute them without having any error. When I execute the SP from a Apache/PHP + PDO I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1934
>   General SQL Server error: Check
>   messages from the SQL Server [1934]
>   (severity 16) [(null)]

In fact the error is not shown properly. The real error should be like the following:

> Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   CALCUL_NOTATION_XML2, Line 38 SELECT
>   failed because the following SET
>   options have incorrect settings:
>   'CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL,
>   ANSI_WARNINGS, ANSI_PADDING'. Verify
>   that SET options are correct for use
>   with indexed views and/or indexes on
>   computed columns and/or filtered
>   indexes and/or query notifications
>   and/or XML data type methods and/or
>   spatial index operations.

My SP looks something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TEST_XML(
    @MyXML XML
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @MyXML = '<SampleXML>
    <Colors>
        <Color1>White</Color1>
    </Colors>
    <Fruits>
        <Fruits1>Apple</Fruits1>
    </Fruits>
    </SampleXML>'

    SELECT
    a.b.value('Colors[1]/Color1[1]','varchar(10)') AS Color1,
    a.b.value('Fruits[1]/Fruits1[1]','varchar(10)') AS Fruits1,
    FROM @MyXML.nodes('SampleXML') a(b) 
END
```

The error only happens because of the way PDO connect to the database. It use the following options:

```
-- network protocol: TCP/IP
set quoted_identifier off
set arithabort off
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings off
set ansi_padding off
set concat_null_yields_null off
set ansi_nulls off
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language us_english
set dateformat mdy
set datefirst 7
set transaction isolation level read committed
```

I wonder if it would be possible to change the login setup in PDO to have something that looks more like:

```
set quoted_identifier on
set arithabort on
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings on
set ansi_padding on
set ansi_nulls on
set concat_null_yields_null on
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language Français
set dateformat dmy
set datefirst 1
set transaction isolation level read committed
```

I have read on a [site](http://gullele.wordpress.com/2010/12/15/accessing-xml-column-of-sql-server-from-php-pdo/), a kind of workaround, but I wonder if there is a real solution (like configuring PDO I don't know how to make it work).